# Active Admin undefined methodgenerate_association_input_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I'm using this active_admin on Rails. I had one model: Page. But then I ran some migrations. When I came back to the login panel on active admin, whenever I would click on the Pages button at the top navigation bar, I get this error:

NoMethodError in Admin/pages#index

Showing /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeadmin-0.3.1/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `generate_association_input_name' for #
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: render renderer_for(:index)

Another model I created works fine. I don't know what I did to break the Page model on Active Admin.

I'm going to try to regenerate active admin.

Comment: I looked at the log and I get this warning: Processing by ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
DEPRECATION WARNING: Formtastic::SemanticFormBuilder has been deprecated in favor of Formtastic::FormBuilder. (called from realtime at /home/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310)

Comment: I ended up downgrading formtastic to 1.2.4.beta https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/issues/577

Comment: You should downgrade to 1.2.4 - not 1.2.4.beta. Though the beta tag is heigher in the list than the non-beta tag it's actually an older tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Formtastic (which is a Active Admin dependency) was just updated to version 2.0.0 [4 days ago](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/commit/b669fd2af0ce6f66790ac7267ba34e1945785f80).

Previously Active Admin depended on Formtastic >= 1.1.0, which includes v2. But v2 have changed so much that it breaks Active Admin. 3 days ago mattvague [made an update](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/commit/bc7c5563b7e3e435033150f3ad46c6dfabb4e70e) to Active Admin to reflect this issue, binding Active Admin to Formtastic < 2.0.0.

So if if you don't mind upgrading Active Admin you can fix this by upgrading to Active Admin 0.3.2 which includes this fix:

```
gem 'activeadmin', '~> 0.3.2'
```

Alternatively you can force Active Admin to use an older version of Formtastic by adding it manually to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'formtastic', '1.2.4' # an activeadmin dependency
gem 'activeadmin', '< 0.3.2' # or whatever version below 0.3.2 you depend on
```